# Creating IOS simulator build but missing prefabs

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

When, for the first time, i create an IOS build for my Unity3D test game i miss the main graphical objects in the simulator.

I am creating a card game but non of the cards, prefabs, are showing up in the xcode simulator, all other objects seems to be OK and the simulator seems to work. Also, no problem in Unity3D when testing.

Anyone that have any idea about the reason for this and why this happen?

Here is the log from XCODE:

```
2014-12-25 10:27:17.041 ProductName[6791:104969] -> registered mono modules 0xe08320

-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()

Mono path[0] = '/Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed'

Mono config path = '/Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed'

PlayerConnection initialized from /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data (debug = 0)

PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55000

Multi-casting "[IP] 10.0.1.56 [Port] 55000 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 632824958 [EditorId] 1881321028 [Version] 1048832 [Id] iPhonePlayer(Peters-MacBook-Pro-2.local):56000 [Debug] 1" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...

Waiting for connection from host on [10.0.1.56:55000]...

Timed out. Continuing without host connection.

Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56000

PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [10.0.1.56:55000]

2014-12-25 10:27:22.262 ProductName[6791:104969] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

2014-12-25 10:27:22.262 ProductName[6791:104969] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78773910 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

2014-12-25 10:27:22.263 ProductName[6791:104969] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

2014-12-25 10:27:22.263 ProductName[6791:104969] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78773910 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

2014-12-25 10:27:22.263 ProductName[6791:104969] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

2014-12-25 10:27:22.273 ProductName[6791:104969] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78773910 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

2014-12-25 10:27:22.274 ProductName[6791:104969] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

2014-12-25 10:27:22.274 ProductName[6791:104969] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78773910 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

2014-12-25 10:27:22.274 ProductName[6791:104969] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

2014-12-25 10:27:22.275 ProductName[6791:104969] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78773910 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

2014-12-25 10:27:22.275 ProductName[6791:104969] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

2014-12-25 10:27:22.275 ProductName[6791:104969] Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x78773910 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

-> applicationDidBecomeActive()

Requesting Resolution: 768x1024

Renderer: Apple Software Renderer

Vendor:   Apple Inc.

Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-10.1.5

GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_comp

ression_pvrtc

Creating OpenGLES2.0 graphics device

Initialize engine version: 4.6.1f1 (d1db7a1b5196)

Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly

Platform assembly: /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)

Loading /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain

Platform assembly: /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)

Loading /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain

Platform assembly: /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll (this message is harmless)

Loading /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll into Unity Child Domain

Platform assembly: /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)

Loading /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain

- Completed reload, in  0.011 seconds

Platform assembly: /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)

Platform assembly: /Users/PeterK/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E6293AA-2882-441F-9109-F2F66672910C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916E3424-135D-47D1-95F7-D45EAAB250F4/ProductName.app/Data/Managed/System.dll (this message is harmless)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem partly solved:**

I have solved the basic problem by finding a second PlayerPref read for cardScaleVector that i deleted. However, I still do not understand why it worked in the Editor but not in XCODE. Well, i guess i have to accept it as it now works :-)